# Keno UI dropdown list display more fields and then display

Tags: json, kendo-ui

I am trying to display the Json data through kendo drop down list.
I have bind the Json data to java script variable named accounts. It has name,id,code,city,state attributes.

I am trying to display all these attributes.But unable to do that . below is a code which i have created . Kindly help me or provide directions.

```
function DisplayAccounts(res) {
  var accounts = [];
  var response = $.parseJSON(res);
  for (var idx = 0; idx < response.length; idx++)
  {
    accounts.push({ 
      'name': response[idx].AccountName,        
      'accountid': response[idx].AccountId, 
      'accountcode': response[idx].AccountCode,
      'city':response[idx].City,
      'state':response[idx].State,
      'ce':response[idx].CE
    });  
  }

  $('#accountSelect').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",+"city"+"sate",
    dataValueField: "accountid",+"accountcode"

    dataSource: accounts

  });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use templates:

```
$('#accountSelect').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "accountid",
    template: '#: name #, #: city#, #: state#',
    valueTemplate: '#: accountid # == #: accountcode #',
    dataSource: accounts
});
```

This is only for visual formatting. You can't format input value. It can be only single column from data source

Answer (score 1):

Try combining values before push and use them as key and value fields.

```
function DisplayAccounts(res) {
  var accounts = [];
  var response = $.parseJSON(res);
  for (var idx = 0; idx < response.length; idx++)
  {
    accounts.push({ 
      'name' : response[idx].AccountName+' '+response[idx].City+' '+response[idx].State,      
      'accountid': response[idx].AccountId+' '+response[idx].AccountCode 

    });  
  }

  $('#accountSelect').kendoDropDownList({
    dataTextField: "name",
    dataValueField: "accountid"

    dataSource: accounts

  });
}
```